# Под какие разрешения рисовать макеты для андроид/ios приложения?

Tags: phonegap, android, ios, iphone, дизайн

Под какие разрешения рисовать макеты для андроид приложения? Приложение будет писаться на phonegap, так что должны быть и разрешения для айфонов и для андроидов. Дизайнеру нужно конкретно сказать, а я никак не могу решить. Может есть где-нибудь статистические данные по расширениям?

Comment: Подстраиваться под флагманы. А там кругом 1920x1080 

UPD1: у него плюс - оно и планшетное и телефонное

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых нужно четко понимать разницу между разрешением экрана, его размером, и глубиной изображения.
Во-вторых, какие нужны экраны для Android приложения очень сильно зависит от того под какие девайсы вы хотите разрабатывать свое приложение. Так как мне жалко андроидщиков очень сильно в этом плане просто ппц как жалко, вот вам в [помощь фрагментация экранов](http://opensignal.com/reports/fragmentation-2013/) по разным сортировкам, экраны нужно будет сопоставить моделям устройств. От этих картинок должны отталкиваться маркетологи, менеджеры по прадажам и прочие люди заинтересованные покрытием рынка. И только после этого они говорят какие расширения вы будете поддерживать для Android устройств, так как и наче верстальщик интерфейсов разбогатеет если вы будете охватывать все девайсы.

В-третьих, что косается iOS устройств, дизайнер должен знать на зубок, как таблицу умножения и разрешения экранов и глубину пиксей и правило формирования имен графических файлов. Дайте ему ссылку на [сюда](http://benlew.com/blog/2012/06/ios-resolution-quick-reference/) и на [офф доку](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Ну и в-четвертых, если дизайнер не освоит соглашения по графике, можете его уволить :)

p.s. Наш дизайнер по андроиду написал специальный скрипт для фотошопа, который режит картинку высого разрешения на разные, заранее запланированные, девайсы изменяя глубину иконок.

Comment: Насколько я знаю в последнем фотошопе есть форма со всеми размерами экранов мобильных устройств

Comment: Bimawa, не хотел бы Ваш дизайнер поделиться скриптиком с общественностью?)

Comment: :) незнаю, спрошу.

Comment: Дал вот эту ссылку: http://blog.mready.net/2013/07/dg-photoshop-action-dpi-resizing/
со словами "а там кастомизируй под себя"